# Batch or Bulk Combining jpg with audio files?

Tags: batch-file, audio, video, ffmpeg

**I want to combine batch jpg with audio files?**
example: I have a folder with 100 .jpg files & 100 .mp3 files in  it.
if 1st jpg file is dog.jpg then corresponding audio file is dog.mp3,
2nd file is cat.jpg then there will be a audio file in same folder naming cat.mp3

okay now coming to point. i want to Batch combine jpg with audio to produce video file like dog.mp4 , cat.mp4 etc. as i have described in the example. could anybody suggest me a better method??
can i use ffmpeg?? then what is command?

For (1 image + 1 audio file = 1 video) case i know the answer its here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887311/ffmpeg-1-image-1-audio-file-1-video

I have a windows system with ffmpeg installed.
thank you in advance for answer.

Comment: what have you tried? what problem you found? is the problem the discovery of all *.jpg files? hint: HELP FOR; is the problem the matching *.mp3 files? hint: HELP IF; is the problem the ffmpeg command? hint: FFMPEG --help

Comment: @PA. problem is ffmpeg command! i dont know the command. can you suggest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in a batch file and run it.  You may need to tweak the `ffmpeg` options to suit your preferences.

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.jpg) do (
   if exist "%%~nF.mp3" ( 
      ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "%%~nF.jpg" -i "%%~nF.mp3" -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec mpeg4 -shortest "%%~nF.mp4" 
   ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks Tony & LordNeckbeard for your Reply, unfortunately, your code didn't work for me .. actually I've been using ffmpeg for just 3 days, so I'm not that advanced user and honestly I Couldn't understand about half of your answer! (Forgive my ignorance). would you please tell me more specific steps to get that job done?

Comment: @JohnMaker, what part don't you understand? Do you know how to create a batch file? Is `ffmpeg` in your path? If not, you'll have to specify its location explicitly, i.e. `"C:\Program Files\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe"` (or wherever it's located on your PC).

Comment: I had saved above code as .bat file inside the folder were all jpg and mp3 files are located. code runs successfully but nothing changes.. what to do? please help! folder location is : C:\Program Files\FFMPEG\bin\  (inside that ffmpeg.exe and all .jpg files and .mp3 files are located)

Comment: Use this at the command line: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "testfile.jpg" -i "testfile.mp3" -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec mpeg4 -shortest "testfile.mp4"`, replacing `testfile` with one of your actual names. Tweak the command line until it works for that one combo, then paste that command back into the batch file with the `%%~` syntax as in the example above.  Make sure your file names are identical (except the extensions), or it won't work.

Comment: thank you man. it works fine.. every thing was fine. for me the codec "libfdk_aac" did'nt works, so i replaced it with "libvo_aacenc"  i was searching for this for a long time.. 100000+ thanks